# Enable Migrations EF 6 Package Not Installed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm creating a new MVC 5 solution using EF 6 code first with membership. I broke out my solution into 3 projects, one consisting of the main project with the views, one is the Core, or business layer, and the third is the Domain. The DataContext and Initializer classes are in the project called 'Core'. When I try to use the Package Manager console to enable-migrations and select the 'Core' project as the default, I get: I am not sure I understand the issue, as I have referenced the Entity Framework libraries within the project.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? TIA

Comment: In Package Manager Console check your `Default project` is set to Core

Comment: It is set to Core. I didn't install anything for Entity Framework, I only reference the .dlls (2 of them). Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to do the NuGet install of the EF package vs. just referencing the DLLs.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but that doesn't work.  Take an empty asp,net 5 project.  Use package manager to install EF6 and try command "enable-migration" and you will get the same error.  It looks like migrations support (which are merely powershell scripts) is broken for asp.net 5 projects.